# MySQL: Elegant way to put a WHERE statement in an IF clause

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with some data:

```
Ticker    Size    Price
A         0       20
A         1       21
B         1       20
B         -1      21
B         -1      22
```

I will like to write a SQL query to return the (volume weighted) average price of each ticker if the overall size is not zero. If the overall size is positive, the average price is the average of only the positive sizes (and vice versa).

For example, in this scenario, the query should return:

```
Ticker    NetSize    VWAP
A         1          21 (average: 21)
B         -1         21.5 (average: 21,22)
```

I tried to come up with a query that looks like:

```
SELECT Ticker, Sum(Size) AS NetSize, 
    IF(SUM(SIZE)>0, (SELECT SUM(Size*Price)/SUM(Size) FROM mysqltable WHERE Size>0 (and many conditions...)),
    IF(SUM(SIZE)<0, (SELECT SUM(Size*Price)/SUM(Size) FROM mysqltable WHERE Size<0 (and many conditions...)),
    0)) AS VWAP
FROM mysqltable
WHERE <many conditions>
```

By doing so however there is a need to repeat the long `WHERE` clause as well as the name of the table. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same thing?

Will really appreciate any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT Ticker, SUM(Size) AS NetSize,
       CASE 
          WHEN SUM(Size) > 0 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN Size > 0 THEN Price END)
          WHEN SUM(Size) < 0 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN Size < 0 THEN Price END)
          ELSE 0
       END AS VWAP       
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Ticker;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/EDPXX90297)

Comment: Hey Giorgos, thank you for your reply. This looks like its going in the right direction and will work in the previous example, but sizes can be both positive and negative for the same ticker. I've updated the question with a different input to show what I mean

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Ticker, Sum(Size) AS NetSize, 
   CASE WHEN SUM(SIZE)>0 THEN SUM(Size*Price)/SUM(Size) 
        WHEN SUM(SIZE)<0 THEN SUM(Size*Price)/SUM(Size)
        ELSE 0 
   END AS VWAP
FROM mysqltable
WHERE <many conditions>
```

Try above query.

You are trying to put same calculation on both the scenario `SUM(SIZE)>0 or SUM(SIZE) < 0`.

I don't think it's make sense.

Still I had put your condition as it is, and try to resolve your issue.